# PHP Session empty after running all night

Tags: php, session, session-storage

I have a program that processes about 20,000+ line CSV files. It reads the file and sends ajax requests containing chunks of data from the CSV file, processes them and returns the results which are displayed with javascript.

This process takes a LONG time, usually 3+ hours.

My problem is I have data stored in session variables that need to be accessed to export the newly processed data. I ran this overnight and when I came back in the morning the processing was done, I clicked export and the session variables are blank.

I checked the session 'lifetime' (session_get_cookie_params()) is set to 0 meaning it should live until the browser is closed.

Besides inserting the data into the URLs and passing it around to function etc is there any way to remedy losing the sessions before the browser is closed?

Comment: doesn't matter what the session cookie lifetime is - it's the server-side session **FILE** lifetime that needs to be extended: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php  (the .gc_* values).

Comment: Sessions are generally considered unreliable for data storage (There are many things to consider such as available memory, browser, TMP dir etc.) For your scenario using a DB is probably the best approach.

Comment: I don't know where the sessions come in exactly, but I would run a job like that directly on the server from the command line using a scheduler like cron in Linux.

Comment: @Boruch - Yes a login on this tool would be ideal, Ive told my boss this several times but thems the requirements...

Comment: @Jeroen - Its a tool for users to come and use, its just massive. And yes we do want the user to be able to upload a csv, navigate away and get an email with the results if possible. Do you have any resources for something like that? (PHP and JS)

Comment: three hours seems like a very long time to process 20k CSV records. What kind of process is this, and why does it take that long to run? Please don't tell me you're running a separate PHP call for each line of the CSV file via ajax from a web UI? That's what it sounds like, and that sounds *unbelievably* inefficient. This kind of thing calls for a batch job, where the entire file is sent to PHP and processed in a loop.

Comment: @RachelD There is no need for js, just have users add a job to a database and have a cron-job check every xx hours or minutes to start all newly added jobs.

Comment: This sounds like a case for building a job/work queue. Its not a good idea to do the processing within a browser session, instead it should happen by a worker, asynchronously from the browser request.

Comment: @SDC - Its a csv of URLs that are put into the database then sorted and certain urls are specially selected to be curled. In the end 6000+ websites are being hit by CURL looking for backlinks, that's why it takes so long. Batch job may be a better idea. Im going to google that. (Bear with me guys this is my first tool that processes SO much I may be doing it wrong, however the tool that I am replacing was waaaay worse and never finished without crashing the browser.)

Comment: @jeroen - The requirements (from management) are for the user to upload a .csv without logging in and to have the results be displayed in real time so the user can see it happening. Hence the ajax and JS. We also want it to run in the background too for larger files like this.

Comment: @RachelD In that case, you may want to have one big job that breaks into alot of little jobs, that way curl can operate on parallel on a lot of sites at the same time. Look at using gearman or another message queue system.

Comment: You are going to have anonymous users hitting your servers with thousands of urls that you are going to curl? Sounds like abuse waiting to happen...

Comment: @datasage - Thats exactly whats going on. Out of the 20,000 urls around 6,000 are selected as valuable (could be more or less, could be all 20,000). Those 6,000 are broken up into groups of 5 and each group is sent via ajax to a php page that curls and looks for a backlink. There are 6 ajax calls going at all times (Unless your in IE but we advise against that).

Comment: @jeroen - Its a tool for internet marketing. At the moment it is only used by our staff. Eventually it will be a paid tool. Other than that all I can say is I'm an employee and this is what the company is paying me to make. Its kind of neat from a programming standpoint :)

Comment: @datasage - Im having a hard time finding a resource for the 'worker' concept your talking about because its a general term. Do you have a wikipedia page you could throw at me or something?

Comment: This just confirms why I hate marketing... Though I agree that from a programming point of view it sounds interesting :-)

Comment: @RachelD It is a pretty general concept. Job queue/message queue sometimes are used interchangeably to mean the same thing. This might be a good page [Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)

Comment: @datasage - Thank you for the link I will really look into this because I know the tool isn't set up ideally. Like I said I've never worked with this much data before and I'm sure the original tool that I based this on wasn't doing it well either.